# AdapterViewFlipper with StackView card flip action

Tags: android, android-appwidget, remoteview, stackview

I've been looking at the sample [StackWidget](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/StackWidget) app, which provides a widget having a `StackView`.  This gives the appearance of a stack of cards, with the ability to flip between cards with a vertical swipe on the widget:

[image]

I like this effect but would prefer to see just one card at a time (filling the widget space), not an offset stack of cards.  Changing `StackView` to `AdapterViewFlipper` (and making it `autoStart` with a `flipInterval`) nearly works:

```
<AdapterViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/stack_view"
    android:autoStart="true"
    android:flipInterval="1000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:loopViews="true" />
```

However, with an `AdapterViewFlipper` it seems like you lose the ability to swipe between cards.

So I'd either like to alter to properties of the `AdapterViewFlipper` to make it work more like a `StackView` in this respect (flipping enabled), or alternatively alter the properties of a `StackView` to make it look more like an `AdapterViewFlipper` (just one card visible at a time).

Comment: Did you find a way to make this work? I'm having the same problem

Comment: @Daantje sorry, no :-(